# Use Linux to share continous RAM between processors

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, driver, shared-memory

I am working with the Zynq 7 of Xilinx. On the Zynq there is a FPGA, an ARM processor and 512 MiB of DDR RAM. When the board is powered on, the ARM processor starts Ubuntu, which initializes the DDR RAM and claims it as its own. On the FPGA, I am developping another processor and I want to give it a piece of DDR memory. Since I am still developing, I would like to somehow allocate a piece of 64 MiB of continous DDR RAM from linux userspace (the device has a MMU). I would then get the start address of this piece of RAM, pass it on to the FPGA processor and it would work with it. While it works on it, I could check if everything is fine from the same program, in Ubuntu.

The question is about the Linux side of this, what would be a good way?

Here is what I gathered myself:
I read a bit about cma, and I noticed that the Ubuntu instance already allocates 128 MiB of cma RAM on boot. So, I think the best way would be to find or develop a driver that takes some of that RAM and "locks" it so that the OS will not give it out to other programs. Then I would still need a way to access it from userspace. Is this the right track of thinking?

Comment: Yes, you need to wrote a driver to oversee this whole process. You call one of the dma_alloc functions to allocate contiguous RAM. Then you are free to let hardware DMA to that memory, and/or let userspace map it into a process' vm.

Comment: Reserving space will be the easy part, as worst case you can do that independently in each system just by making coordinated physical address assignments (often its easiest to misinform Linux about the maximum physical address).  Instead, the real challenge will be that you need **bus arbitration** as the memory presumably has only a single port, that now needs to support two differing architecture processors.

Comment: @ChrisStratton presumably the DDR memory is on a multi-master AHB/AXI bus(since it probably would have to be to support DMA), so that part should "just work".  Both processors better have cache at that point, though.