# Determine architecture when compiling linux module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a kernel module and in it I have the following piece of code:

```
dma_dev->coherent_dma_mask = DMA_BIT_MASK(64);
```

I do not always want 64 in there: when I am targetting ARM, I want it to be

```
dma_dev->coherent_dma_mask = DMA_BIT_MASK(32);
```

So basically, for now I want:

```
#ifdef x86_64
    dma_dev->coherent_dma_mask = DMA_BIT_MASK(64);
#else
    dma_dev->coherent_dma_mask = DMA_BIT_MASK(32);
#endif
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: DMA mask is a property of the device or a platform as a whole. What kind of module do you write? Currently your approach seems wrong.

Comment: @0andriy In another question I explained what I wanted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645953/use-linux-to-share-continous-ram-between-processors. So, I am building a module with malloc-like properties, except that the memory that is allocated is physically continious. If you know a better way, I would love to hear it.

Comment: You are trying to assign DMA mask on behalf of architecture code. This should be done already for you under *arch/<$ARCH>*. On the other hand if your device, which does DMA, needs another setting, you put it in the driver (but it's architecture independent).

Comment: @0andriy I dont get it. Where are you saying I should get my device pointer from?

Comment: You need to understand what you are trying to achieve. 1) If you have a limitation for DMA address space by architecture, it should be provided by architectural code -> your **device, which does DMA,** just inherits it. 2) If your **device, which does DMA,** needs another setting (usually less address space), you need to do this in the driver of the **device, which does DMA,** in question, but in this case it's *architecture independent*.

Comment: @0andriy If I let the default stuff do its thing I end up in a situation where I cannot allocate more than 4 MiB from the DMA functions. I have to introduce the code in this post to fix it. I based it on the following example: https://lwn.net/Articles/485193/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `CONFIG_` definitions for that. Something like this might fit your needs:

```
#if defined(CONFIG_X86_64)
    dma_dev->coherent_dma_mask = DMA_BIT_MASK(64);
#else
    dma_dev->coherent_dma_mask = DMA_BIT_MASK(32);
#endif
```

`CONFIG_ARM` (for 32bit), `CONFIG_ARM64` and similar options may also come in handy.